# Docker for testing contracts

Tags: docker, ubuntu

What are the advantages and disadvantages to using docker for running a local node for writing and testing contracts? So far, developing on a 16.04 Ubuntu vm has worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Docker lately for several reasons.

### Advantages

- Easier than a VM by just running a couple of commands
- I can segregate my host node, keosd and cleos node on 3 different instances in 3 seconds.
- Starting from scratch is a matter of rebooting.
- Debugging or sending my environment to another person might prove useful than working out how to cart around a VM and hoping there's no issues booting the thing if someone else is using a different hypervisor.

### Disadvantages

- Gotta install Docker?
- Small learning curve of Docker compared to someone who's comfortable with VM's. Learning commands,figuring out containers v images etc.

If you'd like to get a taste for how quickly you can spin up an EOS blockchain on Docker checkout the documentation on [EOS Docs](https://www.eosdocs.io/dappdevelopment/software/docker/)